# Failure response retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I Implemented  sample retrofit 2 response via GET type, where I click button to get the response, but I have  Failure response

```
public interface GithubServise {

     @GET("/users/waadalkatheri/repos")
     Call<ResponseBody> getGithub();
    }

    public void loadData (View view){


        String LINK = "https://api.github.com";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ().baseUrl (LINK).build ();
        GithubServise githubServise= retrofit.create (GithubServise.class);
        githubServise.getGithub ().enqueue (new Callback<ResponseBody> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    textView.setText (response.body ().string ());
                    Log.v ("TAG","yes");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
               textView.setText ("no data");

            }
        });
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
 06-25 10:13:00.870 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
 ssl=0xb95dcb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 06-25
 10:13:00.874 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000) 06-25 10:13:00.886
 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:    
 at
 org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:436)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
 06-25 10:13:00.898 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
 06-25 10:13:00.902 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
 06-25 10:13:00.910 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
 06-25 10:13:00.926 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
 06-25 10:13:00.930 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
 06-25 10:13:00.934 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
 06-25 10:13:00.938 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
         at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147) 06-25 10:13:00.942 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 06-25
 10:13:00.946 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 06-25 10:13:00.950 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
 ssl=0xb95dcb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 06-25
 10:13:00.958 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000)
         at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
 Method) 06-25 10:13:00.962
 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:    
 at
 org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
        ... 23 more 06-25 10:13:00.974 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning V/TAG: no data
 06-25 10:13:00.978 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
 ssl=0xb95fea28: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 06-25
 10:13:00.986 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000) 06-25 10:13:01.002
 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:    
 at
 org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:436)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
 06-25 10:13:01.006 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
 06-25 10:13:01.010 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
 06-25 10:13:01.014 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
 06-25 10:13:01.018 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 06-25 10:13:01.022 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
 06-25 10:13:01.026 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
         at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147) 06-25 10:13:01.030 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb95fea28: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol
 error
     error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000)
         at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
 Method)
         at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
 06-25 10:13:01.034 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:  ... 23 more 06-25 10:13:02.586
 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning V/TAG: no data
 06-25 10:13:02.586 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
 ssl=0xb95dcb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 06-25
 10:13:02.590 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000) 06-25 10:13:02.594
 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:    
 at
 org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:436)
 06-25 10:13:02.598 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
 06-25 10:13:02.602 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
 06-25 10:13:02.606 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
         at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
 06-25 10:13:02.610 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
 06-25 10:13:02.614 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 06-25 10:13:02.618 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
 06-25 10:13:02.622 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning
 W/System.err:     at
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
         at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
         at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 06-25 10:13:02.626 2249-2249/com.example.waadalkatheri.retrofittraning W/System.err:
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
 ssl=0xb95dcb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
     error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741
 0x9dc27d4d:0x00000000)
         at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
 Method)
         at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: post you logcat here ??

Comment: I did @sushildlh

Comment: @user4746449 Add this onFailure method t.printStackTrace(); We need more Details about From Logcat

Comment: @user4746449 BaseUrl should be https://api.github.com/ and then remove and change to @GET("users/waadalkatheri/repos")

Comment: @user4746449 and do read the comments at https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3614

Comment: @user4746449: Just an advice outside your question, you should not be dealing with UI updates within the retrofit service, that is going to give you massive headaches in the future. use LiveData instead.

Answer (score 2):

As [seen here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.github.com&s=192.30.255.116&hideResults=on), your api https://api.github.com supports only **`TLS 1.2`**. Your test device might have an android version 16+ and **`TLS 1.2`** is supported in API level 16+, but are not enabled by default.For 20+ devices it is enabled by default. So for **`16<device<20`** create a custom `SSLSocketFactory` with **`TLS 1.2`** enabled like below

**`TLSSocketFactory.java`**

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    delegate = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket());
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
}
```

Now create an **`OkHttpClient`** and add the `client` to retrofit like this

```
    public void loadData (View view){

    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory())
                .build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String LINK = "https://api.github.com";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ().client(client).baseUrl (LINK).build ();
    GithubServise githubServise= retrofit.create (GithubServise.class);
    githubServise.getGithub ().enqueue (new Callback<ResponseBody> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                textView.setText (response.body ().string ());
                Log.v ("TAG","yes");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
           textView.setText ("no data");

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When onFailure gets called it means that the error was in the networking. So something in the conection is not working, maybe you have already checked these things..

Make sure you have internet conection and the url is correct by doing the same http request from your browser on your mobile (Chrome).

Check that in the manifest you have asked for the Internet permission:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: I check but I still have same problem

Comment: Could you execute the app on debug mode and put a breakpoint on the onFailure method and check in the Throwable, if you watch local variables after the code has stopped on your breakpoint, inside the throwable variable there should be a description of the error.